# Why are my SVG bezier curves broken in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, svg

I came across a problem today where diagrams I have created are not working in Firefox when created via `getPointAtLength`. Here is a fiddle showing the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/xfpDA/9/

Note comments at the top of the javascript.

The relevant part of the SVG path is:

```
C189.5,423.237,266.965,390.696,266.965,390.696
```

This works perfectly in Chrome and IE, but Firefox skips right over the curve and just closes the path.

However, a tiny change to the curve is enough to fix the problem:

```
C189.5,423.236,266.965,390.696,266.965,390.696
             ^
```

Why does changing that value by a thousandth make the difference between a pretty curve and a broken SVG?

EDIT: That coordinate is not the only one that can be changed to 'fix' the problem, so it appears that Firefox does not play nicely with high-precision curve values.

Comment: That's odd. I observe that any values between 423.2369842529297 and 423.237014770507 triggers the behaviour, if that can give any clue to the reason.

Comment: Additionally, and I should include this in the main post, you can change some of the other coordinates as well to 'fix' the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox is not able to calculate the length of the curve under some circumstances (e.g. delta=0/0). So the result for that path part is NaN/0/undefined and therefore is not added to the total length and the domain for getPointAtLength is smaller.

Comment: Great. I've seen some other parts of my diagrams just disappearing entirely, as a result of `getTotalLength` returning `NaN`. I found a bug report relevant to that issue (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=972515), but unable to find one about this particular problem.