# Offset when following svg motion path

Tags: css, svg, anime.js

I'm just getting started with svg and anime.js. I'm trying to recreate the [svg motion path](http://animejs.com/documentation/#motionPath) found in the documentation with my own assets. Though, instead of using a div to follow the path, I'm using another path.

I have a simple S shaped path and a circular path that follows it. The problem I'm having is that as the circle goes around the bends in the path it has some sort of offset.

```
<svg width="256" height="112" viewBox="0 0 256 112">
    <path class="path" fill="none" stroke="#000" d="M0.500,64.500 L48.500,64.500 C48.500,64.500 64.500,64.500 64.500,48.500 C64.500,32.500 48.500,32.500 48.500,32.500 L40.500,32.500 C40.500,32.500 24.500,32.500 24.500,16.500 C24.500,0.500 40.500,0.500 40.500,0.500 L88.500,0.500 "/>
    <path class="circle" fill="none" stroke="#000" d="M16.000,8.000 C16.000,8.000 16.000,-0.000 8.000,-0.000 C-0.000,-0.000 -0.000,8.000 -0.000,8.000 C-0.000,8.000 -0.000,16.000 8.000,16.000 C16.000,16.000 16.000,8.000 16.000,8.000 Z" style="position: absolute;"/>
</svg>
```

```
var path = anime.path('.path');

anime({
  targets: '.circle',
    translateX: path('x'),
    translateY: path('y'),
  duration: 4000,
  loop: true,
  easing: 'linear'
});
```

I've looked at the example and tried to figure out why this happens. I've added absolute positioning like it's using, but it still has the offset and I'm not sure why. I've also tried separating the path and the circle into separate svgs, but that didn't seem to work either.

Can any one explain to me why this is and how to fix it? I want the circle to move along the path in the center. Thanks.

Codepen: [RJXabe](https://codepen.io/NicholasJohn16/pen/RJXabe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that motion path animations, like this, work by repositioning the circle so it follows the path.  It does that by simply moving the circle by an amount corresponding to the X,Y coordinates of the path at the particular point in time.

But because your circle is drawn down and to the right of the SVG origin (0,0) (ie the top left), it is consequently positioned down and to the right of the point on the path it is supposed to be.

There are several solutions.  Here are a couple:

**1. Reposition (redraw) the circle so that it is centred at the origin**

```
<path class="circle" fill="none" stroke="#000" d="M8.000,0.000
      C8.000,0.000 8.000,-8.000 0.000,-8.000 C-8.000,-8.000 -8.000,0.000 -8.000,0.000 
      C-8.000,0.000 -8.000,8.000 0.000,8.000 C8.000,8.000 8.000,0.000 8.000,0.000 Z"/>
```

https://codepen.io/PaulLeBeau/pen/eKqKRW

**2. Repostion (with a transform) the circle so that it is centred at the origin**

```
<g class="circle">
  <path ... transform="translate(-8,-8)"/>
</g>
```

We need to use a group here so that the `transform` we have added is not overridden by the transform that anime.js applies.

https://codepen.io/PaulLeBeau/pen/eKqKBv

Comment: Thanks! Any chance you could explain why it goes diagonally when it gets to the third curve instead of following the others? It only seems to do this in Firefox.

Comment: Looks like a bug in Firefox. I will report it.

Comment: Think it could be related to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32465124/why-are-my-svg-bezier-curves-broken-in-firefox

Comment: I was able to fix some of the Firefox issues by adding .001 to the coordinates for that curve.