# How move/animate multiple circles along motion path by SVG Animation

Tags: svg, smil, svg-animationelements

How can move multiple circles along a `<mpath>` (motion path) using SVG SMIL Animation `<<animateMotion>`.

**Problem: About the first 3 4 circles everything was fine.**
**Some circles went "out of orbit" – so they are not correctly aligned with the motion path.**

[image]

```css
.planePath {
    stroke: red;
    stroke-width: .1%;
    stroke-width: .5%;
    stroke-dasharray: 1% 2%;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    fill: none;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid center" style="z-index: 99">
        <svg viewBox="-300 -150 3387 1270" align="center" class="svg-animation">
            <path id="planePath" class="planePath"
            d="M1.50024 430C58.2002 -111.6 853.699 -156.741 889.5 430C925.5 1020 1754 1007.5 1785 430C1816 -147.5 2665.5 -132 2665.5 430C2665.5 1010.27 1847 948 1785 453C1841.5 -83.5 930.282 -187.244 889.5 389C851 933 35 1017.5 1.50024 430Z"/>
            />
            <path style="position:absolute" id="circle2" class="planePath "
            d="M1.50024 430C58.2002 -111.6 853.699 -156.741 889.5 430C925.5 1020 1754 1007.5 1785 430C1816 -147.5 2665.5 -132 2665.5 430C2665.5 1010.27 1847 948 1785 453C1841.5 -83.5 930.282 -187.244 889.5 389C851 933 35 1017.5 1.50024 430Z"/>
            />
            <defs>
                <filter id="filter0_d_0_1" x="0" y="17" width="897" height="847" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                    color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                    <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix" />
                    <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"
                        result="hardAlpha" />
                    <feOffset dy="4" />
                    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2" />
                    <feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="out" />
                    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.25 0" />
                    <feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow_0_1" />
                    <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow_0_1" result="shape" />
                </filter>
                <filter id="filter1_d_0_1" x="926" y="33" width="897" height="847" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                    color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                    <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix" />
                    <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"
                        result="hardAlpha" />
                    <feOffset dy="4" />
                    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2" />
                    <feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="out" />
                    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.25 0" />
                    <feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow_0_1" />
                    <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow_0_1" result="shape" />
                </filter>
                <filter id="filter2_d_0_1" x="1884" y="33" width="897" height="847" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                    color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                    <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix" />
                    <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"
                        result="hardAlpha" />
                    <feOffset dy="4" />
                    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2" />
                    <feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="out" />
                    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.25 0" />
                    <feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow_0_1" />
                    <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow_0_1" result="shape" />
                </filter>
            </defs>

            <g id="plane">
                <circle cx="80" cy="0" r="20" fill="black" />
            </g>
            <g id="point">
                <circle cx="-50" cy="0" r="20" fill="black"/>
            </g>
            <g id="point-2">
                <circle cx="20" cy="0" r="20" fill="black" />
            </g>
            <g id="point-3">
                <circle cx="-120" cy="0" r="20" fill="black" />
            </g>
            <g id="point-4">
                <circle cx="140" cy="0" r="20" fill="black" />
            </g>
            <g id="point-5">
                <circle cx="180" cy="20" r="20" fill="orange" />
            </g>
            <g id="point-6">
                <circle cx="-180" cy="0" r="20" fill="black" />
            </g>
            <g id="point-7">
                <circle cx="-200" cy="0" r="20" fill="black" />
            </g>
            <g id="point-8">
                <circle cx="-220" cy="0" r="20" fill="black" />
            </g>
            <g id="point-9">
                <circle cx="-240" cy="0" r="20" fill="black" />
            </g>
            <g id="point-10">
                <circle cx="-260" cy="0" r="20" fill="black" />
            </g>
            <g id="point-11">
                <circle cx="-280" cy="0" r="20" fill="black" />
            </g>

            <g id="point-12">
                <circle cx="-300" cy="0" r="20" fill="black"/>
            </g>
            <g id="point-13">
                <circle cx="320" cy="0" r="20" fill="black" />
            </g>
            <g id="point-14">
                <circle cx="-340" cy="0" r="20" fill="black" />
            </g>
            <g id="point-15">
                <circle cx="-360" cy="0" r="20" fill="black" />
            </g>
            <g id="point-16">
                <circle cx="-380" cy="0" r="20" fill="black" />
            </g>
            <g id="point-17">
                <circle cx="-400" cy="0" r="20" fill="black" />
            </g>
            <g id="point-18">
                <circle cx="-420" cy="0" r="20" fill="black" />
            </g>
            <g id="point-19">
                <circle cx="-430" cy="0" r="20" fill="black" />
            </g>
            <g id="point-20">
                <circle cx="-440" cy="0" r="20" fill="black" />
            </g>
            <g id="point-21">
                <circle cx="-460" cy="0" r="20" fill="black" />
            </g>
            <g id="point-22">
                <circle cx="-480" cy="0" r="20" fill="black" />
            </g>
            <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
            <animateMotion xlink:href="#plane" dur="20s" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto">
                <mpath xlink:href="#planePath" />
            </animateMotion>
            <animateMotion xlink:href="#point" dur="20s" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto">
                <mpath xlink:href="#planePath" />
            </animateMotion>
            <animateMotion xlink:href="#point-2" dur="20s" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto">
                <mpath xlink:href="#planePath" />
            </animateMotion>
            <animateMotion xlink:href="#point-3" dur="20s" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto">
                <mpath xlink:href="#planePath" />
            </animateMotion>


            <animateMotion xlink:href="#point-4" dur="20s" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto">
                <mpath xlink:href="#planePath" />
            </animateMotion>
            <animateMotion xlink:href="#point-5" dur="20s" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto">
                <mpath xlink:href="#planePath" />
            </animateMotion>
            <!-- <animateMotion xlink:href="#point-6" dur="20s" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto">
                <mpath xlink:href="#planePath" />
            </animateMotion>
            <animateMotion xlink:href="#point-7" dur="20s" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto">
                <mpath xlink:href="#planePath" />
            </animateMotion>
            <animateMotion xlink:href="#point-8" dur="20s" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto">
                <mpath xlink:href="#planePath" />
            </animateMotion>
            <animateMotion xlink:href="#point-9" dur="20s" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto">
                <mpath xlink:href="#planePath" />
            </animateMotion> -->

        </svg>
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="box">
        <div class="circle">
        </div>
        <div class="circle">
        </div>
        <div class="circle">
        </div>
    </div> -->

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your animated circles (moving along the motion path)
should be placed at **cx/cy =0**.
Explained here by @Paul LeBeau: [Offset when following svg motion path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51221123/offset-when-following-svg-motion-path#51230329)

Otherwise their initial position will be added to the current motion path position.
That's why your circle are moving as in straight line around the path.

#### Path offset via animation delay

Actually all circles have the same center position of `cx="0"` `cy="0"` - so they would be overlapping without animation.

By adding an incremental `begin` value we mimic a path offset like so:

```
<animateMotion xlink:href="#plane" dur="10s" begin="0s"repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto">
    <mpath xlink:href="#planePath" />
</animateMotion>
<animateMotion xlink:href="#point-1" dur="10s" begin="0.1s" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto">
    <mpath xlink:href="#planePath" />
</animateMotion>
```

The higher the `begin="0.1s"` value, the larger the distance between the circles.

We can use also use negative `begin` values to set the distance between elements.

The `begin` value is calculated like so:
delay-increment: -0.1 * total number of circles.

#### Simplified example

```html
<svg viewBox="-300 -150 3387 1270" align="center" class="svg-animation">
            <path id="planePath" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="0.5%" stroke-dasharray="1% 2%"
            stroke-linecap="round"  class="planePath"
                d="M1.50024 430C58.2002 -111.6 853.699 -156.741 889.5 430C925.5 1020 1754 1007.5 1785 430C1816 -147.5 2665.5 -132 2665.5 430C2665.5 1010.27 1847 948 1785 453C1841.5 -83.5 930.282 -187.244 889.5 389C851 933 35 1017.5 1.50024 430Z" />
            />
            <g id="circles">
                <circle id="plane" class="plane" fill="green" cx="0" cy="0" r="20" fill="black" />
                <circle id="point-1" class="point-1" fill="magenta" cx="0" cy="0" r="20" fill="black" />
                <circle id="point-2" class="point-2" fill="purple" cx="0" cy="0" r="20" fill="black" />
                <circle id="point-3" class="point-3" fill="orange" cx="0" cy="0" r="20" fill="black" />
            </g>
            <animateMotion xlink:href="#plane" dur="10s" begin="-0.3s"repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto">
                <mpath xlink:href="#planePath" />
            </animateMotion>
            <animateMotion xlink:href="#point-1" dur="10s" begin="-0.2s" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto">
                <mpath xlink:href="#planePath" />
            </animateMotion>
            <animateMotion xlink:href="#point-2" dur="10s" begin="-0.1s" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto">
                <mpath xlink:href="#planePath" />
            </animateMotion>
            <animateMotion xlink:href="#point-3" dur="10s" begin="0s" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto">
                <mpath xlink:href="#planePath" />
            </animateMotion>

        </svg>
```

#### Initial motion path offset – css `offset-path` to the rescue

**Disclaimer:** browser support might still be spotty.
See also [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/offset-path).

The main benefit of the `offset-path` property is its ability to actually define a start offset – pretty neat for static element renderings as well.
(Quite similar to svg's `textPath` related `startOffset` property)

```js
const svg = document.querySelector('svg');
let dotsCount = 15;
let steps = 100 / dotsCount;
let duration = 10;
let circleRadius = 20;
let startOffset = 50;

//create css rules for animations
let circleMarkup = '';
let css = 
`.css-animate circle {
offset-path: path('M1.50024 430C58.2002 -111.6 853.699 -156.741 889.5 430C925.5 1020 1754 1007.5 1785 430C1816 -147.5 2665.5 -132 2665.5 430C2665.5 1010.27 1847 948 1785 453C1841.5 -83.5 930.282 -187.244 889.5 389C851 933 35 1017.5 1.50024 430Z');
offset-rotate: auto;
}`;

for (let i = 0; i < dotsCount; i++) {
    circleMarkup +=
        `<circle id="point${i}" class="point point${i}" fill="green" cx="0" cy="0" r="${circleRadius}" />`;
    css +=
`.point${i} {
offset-distance: ${steps*i+startOffset}%;
animation: followpath${i} ${duration}s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes followpath${i} {
to {
offset-distance: ${100+steps*i+startOffset}%;
}
}`;
}

svg.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<style>'+css+'</style>');
svg.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', circleMarkup);
```

```html
    <svg viewBox="-300 -150 3387 1270" class="css-animate">
        <path id="planePath" stroke="#ccc" stroke-width="1%" stroke-dasharray="1% 2%"
 stroke-linecap="round" fill="none" class="planePath"
            d="M1.50024 430C58.2002 -111.6 853.699 -156.741 889.5 430C925.5 1020 1754 1007.5 1785 430C1816 -147.5 2665.5 -132 2665.5 430C2665.5 1010.27 1847 948 1785 453C1841.5 -83.5 930.282 -187.244 889.5 389C851 933 35 1017.5 1.50024 430Z" />
    </svg>
```

In the above example the initial motion path offset is set by:

```
.point-1 {
    offset-distance: 25%;
    animation: followpath1 10s linear infinite;
}
```

Also referring to a `@keyframe` animation rule:

```
@keyframes followpath1 {
    to {
        offset-distance: 125%;
    }
}
```

Of course, you will need to adjust the values according to the desired offsets/timings.

#### Alternative: animated `stroke-dashoffset`

Probably the easiest approach – slightly jittery.
I use `pathLength` to change the computed length for the dash-array to 100.

```
stroke-dasharray: 0 6.666;
stroke-linecap: round;
```

Setting the first dash-array value to 0 will result in a dotted line (so every dot is perfectly circular) when combined with `stroke-linecap: round`.

The second value defines the the gap or the total number of dots:
100 (pathlength) / 15 (3 circles à 5 dots) = 0.666.

```css
.planePath {
            stroke: red;
            stroke-width: 5%;
            stroke-dasharray: 0 6.666;
            stroke-linecap: round;
            fill: none;
             animation: animStroke 10s linear infinite; 
            stroke-dashoffset: 0;

        }

        .planePath2 {
            stroke: red;
            stroke-width: 5%;
            stroke-dasharray: 0 3.333;
            stroke-linecap: round;
            fill: none;
            animation: animStroke 10s linear infinite;
        }

    
        @keyframes animStroke {
            to {
                stroke-dashoffset: -100;
            }
        }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid center" style="z-index: 99">
        <svg viewBox="-300 -150 3387 1270" align="center" class="svg-animation">
            <path id="planePath" pathLength="100" class="planePath"
                d="M1.50024 430C58.2002 -111.6 853.699 -156.741 889.5 430C925.5 1020 1754 1007.5 1785 430C1816 -147.5 2665.5 -132 2665.5 430C2665.5 1010.27 1847 948 1785 453C1841.5 -83.5 930.282 -187.244 889.5 389C851 933 35 1017.5 1.50024 430Z" />
            />
        </svg>
    </div>


    <div class="container-fluid center" style="z-index: 99">
        <svg viewBox="-300 -150 3387 1270" align="center" class="svg-animation">
            <path id="planePath2" pathLength="100" class="planePath planePath2"
                d="M1.50024 430C58.2002 -111.6 853.699 -156.741 889.5 430C925.5 1020 1754 1007.5 1785 430C1816 -147.5 2665.5 -132 2665.5 430C2665.5 1010.27 1847 948 1785 453C1841.5 -83.5 930.282 -187.244 889.5 389C851 933 35 1017.5 1.50024 430Z" />
            />
        </svg>
    </div>
```

Comment: Wow, nice pro !!! Can you help me, control the initial position of the marble
For example: 5 balls in circle 1, 5 balls in circle 2, 5 balls in circle 3.
Then it will keep moving on 3 circles :(

Comment: @Yun: check the additional example. css `offset-path` might be the better approach to get an intial starting offset. Otherwise please provide a mockup/image of the desired rendering.

Comment: I added image of the desired rendering above. Thank you bro @herrstrietzel

Comment: @Yun: updated the last examples: Now I've described pretty much any approach. It's up to you to test which one suits best for your needs;)