# Motion path by Anime JS is not aligned properly to path

Tags: animation, svg, anime.js

So I created an SVG which is consists of path and shapes and i want to animate those shapes on that specific path.

For animation I am using **anime.js**

[image: elements on motion path]

I have attached my code here :

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/svg-pos-5xlf6y?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A9%2C1

can some one point out the issue or high i can do the alignment using js.

I want to know the issue in my code or svg or a javascript code for proper alignment.

Comment: in the case of the rect the left upper corner is following the path. Please try adding x="-25" y="-25" and see what happens

Comment: Elements moved along a motion path won't auto-snap/align to the motion path. In other words: their intrinsic x/y coordinates are interpreted as offsets while animating. Set the initial elements x/y positions to x: 0-element.width/2 and y: 0-element.height/2 and they are perfectly aligned to the motion path. See also @Paul LeBeau's answer: [Offset when following svg motion path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51221123/offset-when-following-svg-motion-path#51230329). Worth mentioning this is not specific to anime.js besides this will also apply to native SVG motion paths or CSS offset-paths

Comment: This related post may also be helpful ["How move/animate multiple circles along motion path by SVG Animation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73135195/how-move-animate-multiple-circles-along-motion-path-by-svg-animation)