# animateMotion animates my circle on the same path but elsewhere as if translated

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to simply animate a circle along an elliptical path but when using the "animateMotion " tag, the circle seems to get translated towards the bottom-right, then animated.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #212121;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

svg {
  height: 25%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  fill: none;
  stroke: rosybrown;
  overflow: visible;
}

svg circle {
  fill: peru;
  stroke: none;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="20 60 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path
        id="path-1"
        className="path-1"
        translate="-50% -50%"
        d="M53.194026947021484,109.28645324707031C53.194026947021484, 82.82719674465584, 62.81193748083353, 61.37773132324219, 74.67623138427734, 61.37773132324219,C86.54052528772115, 61.37773132324219, 96.1584358215332, 82.82719674465584, 96.1584358215332, 109.28645324707031,C96.1584358215332, 135.74570974948477, 86.54052528772115, 157.19517517089844, 74.67623138427734, 157.19517517089844,C62.81193748083353, 157.19517517089844, 53.194026947021484, 135.74570974948477, 53.194026947021484, 109.28645324707031,z"
      />
      <circle
        className="page-1"
        ref="{page1Ref}"
        cx="60.184269"
        cy="75.187714"
        r="3.9213545"
      >
        <animateMotion dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite">
          <mpath href="#path-1" />
        </animateMotion>
      </circle>
</svg>
```

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
The problem was the cx and cy attributes of the Circle element. They are used to position the element on the x-axis and y-axis respectively and, in this case, they became an offset as pointed out by @herrstrietzel.

CSS:

```css
* {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
      background-color: #212121;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    svg {
      height: 25%;
      aspect-ratio: 1;
      fill: none;
      stroke: rosybrown;
      overflow: visible;
    }

    svg circle {
      fill: peru;
      stroke: none;
    }
```

HTML(removed the invalid translate attribute as pointed out by @RobertLongson. The transform attribute would be the correct attribute) :

```html
<svg viewBox="20 60 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path
            id="path-1"
            className="path-1"
            d="M53.194026947021484,109.28645324707031C53.194026947021484, 82.82719674465584, 62.81193748083353, 61.37773132324219, 74.67623138427734, 61.37773132324219,C86.54052528772115, 61.37773132324219, 96.1584358215332, 82.82719674465584, 96.1584358215332, 109.28645324707031,C96.1584358215332, 135.74570974948477, 86.54052528772115, 157.19517517089844, 74.67623138427734, 157.19517517089844,C62.81193748083353, 157.19517517089844, 53.194026947021484, 135.74570974948477, 53.194026947021484, 109.28645324707031,z"
          />
          <circle
            className="page-1"
            ref="{page1Ref}"
            r="3.9213545"
          >
            <animateMotion dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite">
              <mpath href="#path-1" />
            </animateMotion>
          </circle>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Just reset the `cx` and `cy` values to zero. Otherwise these values are trated as additional offset. See [Offset when following svg motion path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51221123/offset-when-following-svg-motion-path)

Comment: translate is not a valid attribute on a path.

Comment: @herrstrietzel Thank you, that solved it. Makes sense now. I'm new to working with SVGs so I'm still stumbling a little.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks for catching that. I was trying different attributes to try and rectify the issue and it was auto-suggested when I tried it so I assumed it was a valid.