# svg won't show up in firefox but loads in chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, svg

I am loading an 404.svg at certain scenarios into a `div` dynamically.

The svg is getting loaded in chrome but it never does in Firefox for some reason and I haven't checked it in other browsers.

I got the svg from some free SVG providing websites and this is the inside code of svg (can't upload svg directly here stackoverflow limitation ) :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 503.322 503.322" style="enable-background:new 0 0 503.322 503.322;" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <rect x="182.194" y="408.711" style="fill:#95A5A5;" width="138.847" height="77.017"/>
    <path style="fill:#3F5C6C;" d="M166.617,0.195H34.712C15.534,0.195,0,15.121,0,43.195v338.441c0,8.548,15.534,23.474,34.712,23.474
        H468.61c19.178,0,34.712-14.926,34.712-23.474V43.195c0-28.073-15.534-42.999-34.712-42.999H166.617z"/>
    <g>
        <path style="fill:#BDC3C7;" d="M138.847,468.415h225.627c14.378,0,26.034,11.656,26.034,26.034v8.678H112.814v-8.678
            C112.814,480.071,124.469,468.415,138.847,468.415z"/>
        <path style="fill:#BDC3C7;" d="M503.322,365.364v27.509c-0.43,18.754-15.957,33.621-34.712,33.237H34.712
            C15.957,426.495,0.43,411.627,0,392.873v-27.509H503.322z"/>
    </g>
    <path style="fill:#D25627;" d="M346.612,69.228h45.932c18.28,0.912,32.386,16.428,31.557,34.712v86.78
        c0.829,18.284-13.276,33.8-31.556,34.712H108.538c-18.28-0.912-32.385-16.428-31.556-34.712v-86.78
        c-0.829-18.284,13.276-33.8,31.556-34.712H346.612z"/>
    <g>
        <path style="fill:#ECF0F1;" d="M198.475,156.008h-8.678v-8.678c0-4.793-3.885-8.678-8.678-8.678c-4.793,0-8.678,3.885-8.678,8.678
            v8.678h-19.754l27.288-47.763c2.366-4.16,0.917-9.449-3.238-11.823c-4.155-2.374-9.447-0.937-11.83,3.213l-34.712,60.746
            c-1.537,2.685-1.527,5.986,0.026,8.662c1.553,2.676,4.414,4.323,7.508,4.321h34.712v17.356c0,4.793,3.885,8.678,8.678,8.678
            c4.793,0,8.678-3.885,8.678-8.678v-17.356h8.678c4.793,0,8.678-3.885,8.678-8.678
            C207.153,159.893,203.267,156.008,198.475,156.008z"/>
        <path style="fill:#ECF0F1;" d="M363.356,156.008h-8.678v-8.678c0-4.793-3.885-8.678-8.678-8.678s-8.678,3.885-8.678,8.678v8.678
            h-19.754l27.288-47.763c2.366-4.16,0.917-9.449-3.238-11.823c-4.155-2.374-9.447-0.937-11.83,3.213l-34.712,60.746
            c-1.537,2.685-1.527,5.986,0.026,8.662c1.553,2.676,4.414,4.323,7.508,4.321h34.712v17.356c0,4.793,3.885,8.678,8.678,8.678
            s8.678-3.885,8.678-8.678v-17.356h8.678c4.793,0,8.678-3.885,8.678-8.678C372.034,159.893,368.149,156.008,363.356,156.008z"/>
        <path style="fill:#ECF0F1;" d="M259.22,95.262h-17.356c-14.372,0.016-26.018,11.662-26.034,26.034v52.068
            c0.016,14.372,11.662,26.018,26.034,26.034h17.356c14.372-0.016,26.018-11.662,26.034-26.034v-52.068
            C285.239,106.925,273.592,95.278,259.22,95.262z M267.898,173.364c-0.005,4.791-3.887,8.673-8.678,8.678h-17.356
            c-4.791-0.005-8.673-3.887-8.678-8.678v-52.068c0.005-4.791,3.887-8.673,8.678-8.678h17.356c4.791,0.005,8.673,3.887,8.678,8.678
            V173.364z"/>
    </g>
    <path style="fill:#D25627;" d="M137.763,268.822l-34.712,52.068h-8.678c-9.574-0.028-17.328-7.782-17.356-17.356v-17.356
        c0.028-9.574,7.782-17.328,17.356-17.356H137.763z"/>
    <g>
        <path style="fill:#E57E25;" d="M424.136,286.178v17.356c-0.028,9.574-7.782,17.328-17.356,17.356h-43.39l34.712-52.068h8.678
            C416.353,268.85,424.108,276.604,424.136,286.178z"/>
        <polygon style="fill:#E57E25;" points="181.153,268.822 146.441,320.889 103.051,320.889 137.763,268.822         "/>
    </g>
    <polygon style="fill:#D25627;" points="224.542,268.822 189.831,320.889 146.441,320.889 181.153,268.822     "/>
    <polygon style="fill:#E57E25;" points="267.932,268.822 233.22,320.889 189.831,320.889 224.542,268.822     "/>
    <polygon style="fill:#D25627;" points="311.322,268.822 276.61,320.889 233.22,320.889 267.932,268.822     "/>
    <polygon style="fill:#E57E25;" points="354.712,268.822 320,320.889 276.61,320.889 311.322,268.822     "/>
    <polygon style="fill:#D25627;" points="398.102,268.822 363.39,320.889 320,320.889 354.712,268.822     "/>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
</svg>
```

and this is how I dynamically add the svg:

```
imgDiv.innerHTML = `<img class="image" id="cardImage" src="404.svg" alt="404" style="box-shadow: none"/>`;
```

how to load the `SVG` properly into all browsers ?

Comment: giving the SVG a height and width might help. If not we're going to need an actual [mcve] here. I.e. something we can run ourselves.

Comment: Why there is need to modify the svg it works in chrome. so it should be related to firefox and i dammit forgot to add firefox tag.

Comment: I don't know since there's not enough information to see what the problem is. The SVG itself displays so it depends how you're using it.

Comment: the svg is fine the implementation is (i think) fine. and i've posted the code that i am using. What other information i should give ?

Comment: The SVG has no height and width attributes on the root element. If you define how big the SVG is, does it display?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do only the first two curves of this SVG display in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64433552/why-do-only-the-first-two-curves-of-this-svg-display-in-firefox)

Comment: @PeterO. That can't be it because the image does display. Run the snippet.

Comment: ohkay @RobertLongson That worked I was adding the width as width: "200" instead of width="200"

Comment: Ahh that's a Chrome bug then because units are mandatory in CSS.

Comment: @RobertLongson ah nah, I added the height and width to the svg file not in the css So maybe chrome doing some other magics to load the svg without those two.

Comment: The SVG was loaded by Firefox, you couldn't see it because it had 0 height and 0 width. Not sure what Chrome is doing to render something without width and height as having width and height.

Comment: that's why i called it magic though. BTW Firefox is loading the svg if throw it directly to the browser so this is related to how html is getting implemented in firefox and chrome